# Is it possible to extend QColorDialog ui (c++)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a dialog in QT c++ that asks for a color and some data input in text fields. I wanted to combine the color picker and text fields in the same dialog. Is it possible to somehow extend the QColorDialog to add this extra functionality or is there a better way without making my own color picker widget?

Comment: Kind of opinion-based, but extending `QColorDialog` sounds very painful. I would just combine the things you need in a new widget.

Comment: It is still just a normal Qt dialog. You can use introspection and layout/parent/child widget structure to explore the inner structure of the dialog (layout etc.). And you will probably be able to inject some custom widgets into it. It all depends on the specific things you need. Maybe it is possible, maybe not. But the inner structure is implementation detail which can theoretically change in the future (but practically - it will not). Alternatively you can copy the source code from Qt and change it the way you like for your own version of dialog.

Comment: @pptaszni, I was thinking that too, but will I need to make my own color picker or is it possible to get the color picker qt used as a widget to add to my own dialog? I didn't find such a widget.

Comment: Depends how exactly you want it to look, but I think you can just create a widget with a button that will call `QColorDialog::getColor` and next to it some text fields. Hard to tell without specific implementation.

Comment: @pptaszni, yes that's probably the easiest but still clean looking solution as I really didn't want to make two concurrent dialogs but this way it will work well.